# Can I develop different layouts( UI ) for gingerbread, ICS and Kitkat for the same app?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

as I saw that some new APIs were came in ICS which is not available in gingerbread ,but I want to use this in my app and I want my min sdk version also 2.3, how can I do this ?

Can I develop two different user interface for the two different version of android in the same app.

like we can develop UI for different screen sizes by using `layout-sw600dp` or whatever we want ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-vNN` resource set qualifier. `res/layout/` would be used by default; `res/layout-v11/` would be used by API Level 11+ devices; `res/layout-v14/` would be used by API Level 14+ devices; etc.